# include layout not giving access to its class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, include

I want to add different layouts in one activity with its functionalities. When I use include to add layouts it just shows the layout, not the functionalities that I have written in that layouts activity

Comment: Layout XML files have nothing to do with Activities, they're just a description of a bunch of Views to create, and how to style and arrange them. You can create an *Activity* that uses a particular XML layout, and set up some functionality that works with that layout - but it doesn't affect the layout file itself, or anything else that happens to use it. If you want a component with its own functionality that you can just drop into a layout or another component, you probably want a `Fragment`

Comment: but I want functionality of that layout as well

Comment: The layout *has* no functionality of its own (unless you're using the data binding library, but that still requires other components getting wired up to work). Like you say, the functionality is in the `Activity` you've created which uses that particular layout. You'd need to be able to embed the `Activity` in your other `Activity` to get that functionality, but you can't - you can only have one at a time. That's what `Fragment`s were created for: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` can achieve your objective.

You can understand more about fragments from this code lab.
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-fragments

Comment: but I don't want to use fragments